# Can I close a msgbox or userform with a keypress when I have a different application in focus?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a userform that helps me schedule staff.
I get sent a table with next weeks staff and I need to put that in to our time keeping software.
What I do is I copy the table and have VBA loop through the days, find the correct persons (because there could be spelling mistakes), I then switch over to the web browser and place the cursor in the Employee field and VBA uses sendkeys to filter all the staff.
This saves me a ton of time.

But between say Monday and Tuesday I need to "do stuff in the browser", so I added a msgbox that pauses the code for me.
When I'm done with Monday and I'm ready for filtering Tuesday I press OK on the msgbox, go back to the browser and set the cursor in the Employee field.

And here's the thing. I keep having to switch between Excel and browser to press OK.
Can I somehow press OK while I still have the browser as my in focus window, or if I replace the msgbox with a userform that does the same thing (meaning give me a pause in the code until I'm ready) can I close the userform with some hotkey while Excel is not in focus?

Comment: Why not use ALT+TAB to switch between Applications (excel,Browser)

Comment: I realize this sounds a bit lazy but.. I could do that, but ALT+TAB just gets me to Excel, then I need to press OK also, or Enter. Enter is on the other side of the keyboard so I need to either move my left hand or drop the mouse and press Enter. My hope was that I could keep my hands in the optimum position and not have to move the mouse over to the other screen to press OK. Sorry I realize how this sounds, but I'm trying to make it more efficient :-)

Comment: an ok msgbox you can exit with esc and if you have a userform make the ok button a cancel key. Esc is on the same side of the keyboard :-)

Comment: Why doing this: "I then switch over to the web browser and place the cursor in the Employee field and VBA uses sendkeys to filter all the staff"? What kind of browser do you use? I think it should be better to identify "Employee field" and use it to drop the necessary data... For Chrome I have in mind Selenium.

Comment: Sadly it's a work PC and they don't allow any software that is outside of their norm. But I can use Edge or Chrome. Edge is the preferred by IT and also by me. I really like the way I can ALT+TAB between tabs

Comment: @RedHare I will try the ESC button. I haven't thought about that.